# How to use a separate external IP Address in VM Ware Workstation 15?

Tags: windows, server, ip-address, vmware, vmware-workstation

I have a server with 2 external IP-Addresses as listet below.
It is possible to connect to the server with RDP for both IPs.

[image]

Now I have a Virtual Windows 10 in VM Ware Workstation 15.
How can I use the second IP-Address in my VM whily the first one is used on the host?

I can't find any instructions in the web....

**What I want at the end:**

Server 2016 (Host) in Web: https://whatismyipaddress.com => 95.xxx.xxx.156

Windows 10 (VM) in Web: https://whatismyipaddress.com => 95.xxx.xxx.112

Comment: Have you enabled RDP and configured your firewall rules to allow connections on both IPs for the port you've assigned to RDP?

Comment: Yes I did. I can connect to the server (Host) over both IPs.